# SQL insert of multiple records, phpMyAdmin only shows one row

Tags: php, mysql, insert, phpmyadmin

I'm entering (via PHP) records to a table using insert SQL command, but only one record shows up at all times in phpMyAdmin for the corresponding table.

Example: Table **test1** has only one column called id. Here's the `insert` command:

```
mysql_query( "INSERT INTO test1 Values(1)" );
mysql_query( "INSERT INTO test1 Values(2)" );
```

But in phpMyAdmin I only see the first record showing up. Why is that?

Comment: If the Id field is an identity field, you don't need to specify an id...

Comment: you can use mysql_affected_rows and mysql_error to check whether the row has been inserted.

Comment: Do you have an auto-incrementing primary key?

Comment: ya how exactly do i do an auto incrementing primary key?

Comment: Sorry for the delay.  You can do it when setting up your table via php or from your DB admin tool (phpMyAdmin).  To set it up from phpMyAdmin you click the table name on the left frame.  On the right you'll see "Add [1] field(s) at..." Make sure you check the radio button "at beginning of table" and hit "go".  For the field type "id" or whatever you like ("id" is common).  Then set the data type to "int".  From the Attributes select "unsigned" and from the Extra drop down select "auto-increment".  Set Default to 1.  Then click the radio button associated with "Primary".

Answer (score -1):

it will accept if u write in this way
 mysql_query( "INSERT INTO test1 Values(1),(2)" );